# Python regex to identify capitalised single word lines in a text abstract

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to extract words from text if they match the following conditions:
1) are capitalised
and
2) appear on a new line on their own (i.e. no other text on the same line).

I am able to extract all capitalised words with this code:
   *caps=re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]+\b", mytext)*

but can't figure out how to implement the second condition. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `re.MULTILINE` flag to make `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of a line, rather than the beginning and the end of a string:

```
re.findall(r"^[A-Z]+$", mytext, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

please try following statements \r\n at the begining of your regex expression